# Admob randomizing interstitial ad popup time

Tags: flutter, dart, admob, interstitial

Hello I wanted to seek help regarding admob interstitial ad.
My query is can I display a random interstitial ad popup after every 2, 3, 5 minutes on the screen?

I'm really confused. Is it against policy?

My application is very simple it has a webview,
and what I want to is that to just display an interstitial ad after some random minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all the Admob tutorials and docs it's recommended to show an interstitial ad *between* user's actions.

From [official doc](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial#some_best_practices):

> Consider whether interstitial ads are the right type of ad for your app.
> Interstitial ads work best in apps with natural transition points. The conclusion of a task within an app, like sharing an image or completing a game level, creates such a point. Because the user is expecting a break in the action, it's easy to present an interstitial ad without disrupting their experience. Make sure you consider at which points in your app's workflow you'll display interstitial ads and how the user is likely to respond.

Furthermore, showing ads periodically is against the [Admob policies](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362#zippy=%2Cdisallowed-example-recurring-interstitials%2Cdisallowed-example-interstitials-that-impact-navigation%2Crecommendation-how-to-fix-a-violation):

> **Interstitials that unexpectedly launch.**
> Don't surprise users with interstitial ads. Placing interstitial ads so that they suddenly appear when a user is focused on a task at hand (e.g. playing a game, filling out a form, reading content) may lead to accidental clicks and often creates a frustrating user experience. For this reason, interstitial ads should only be implemented at logical breaks in between your app's content (e.g. pages, stages, or levels) to ensure that the user is prepared to engage with the ad.

So I would recommend you to implement showing interstitials following Admob rules to avoid any problems or suspending in the future.